# Kähler manifolds deformation equivalent to projective manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed non-projective Kähler manifold. There are three possibilities

1. there is a proper holomorphic submersion $f:X\to \Delta$ with $f^{-1}(0)\cong M$ such that the projective fibers define a dense set in $\Delta$
2. there is no proper holomorphic submersion $f:X\to \Delta$ with $f^{-1}(0)\cong M$ such that the projective fibers define a dense set in $\Delta$ but there is a proper holomorphic submersion $f:X\to \Delta$ with $f^{-1}(0)\cong M$ and at least one projective fiber
3. no proper holomorphic submersion $f:X\to \Delta$ with $f^{-1}(0)\cong M$ has projective fibers.

K3 surfaces satisfy the possibility 1. Voisin has given examples of possibility 3. Does possibility 2 ever arise?